# Open xml file, find url within, open link and search for value - python lxml

Tags: python, xml, url, lxml

I am opening an xml file, with lxml, and am already doing a lot of editing before saving out to a new xml file, all this is working fine.
Within my opened xml, I have a url which links to a web page. In the webpage are some values I would like to record and use in my open xml. I have searched but can't find where to start.

Kind regards.

UPDATE -

I am using the below code to gleam the url from my xml, and this is working. I can then read all the page into the data variable, which prints fine:

```
url = tree.find("//video/products/product/read_only_info/read_only_value[@key='storeURL-GB']")
if url is not None:
    url = url.text
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    data = data.read()
    print data
```

How can I find a particular string buried in the web page, here is a piece of the web page data I want to get:

```
<div id="content">

  <div class="padder">

    <div id="title" class="intro">
      <div class="left">
        <h1>This is the title</h1>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;<span rating-system="bbfc" rating-id="37" class="content-rating">15</span>
        <h2>this is more text</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <a href="https://rthuere.erwerwer.ghty4e.fdfsdf.com" class="view-more">View More In Sci-Fi &amp; Fantasy</a>

      </div>
```

I need to get the value "View More In Sci-Fi & Fantasy" or whatever other value is there.

Kind regards.

Comment: Give a sample xml and code that show what you have done.

Comment: Look at ElementTree and its examples in the Python docs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the text of all a-nodes, you can do it using [Beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print link.text
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Is there na lxml equivalent, as this is what I am already using?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the below code to open and then search for specific text, which is working.

```
data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = data.read()
primaryGenre = data

if "View More In Sci-Fi &amp; Fantasy" in data:
    then do something else
```

Regards.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an **answer**? If you want to ask additional questions, don't do that in an answer. Edit the question instead (or possibly ask a new question).